# Translating the definition of homogeneity/isotropy of free space to the Lagrangian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry

Landaus argument in Mechanics that a free particle is independent of time, space and direction hinges on homogeneity of space/time and isotropy. At first I was under the assumption these simply meant that if $q(t)$ extremizes the action over a certain time interval:
$q(t)+a$ will maximize it as well (homogeneity of space), which describes the same trajectory evolving with a different point of origin (I throw a ball here and it will have the same trajectory when I throw it 5 meters away, just shifted over 5 meters)

$\int_{t_i+a}^{t_f+a}L(q(t),\dot q(t), t)\mathrm{dt}=\int_{t_i}^{t_f}L(q(t+a),\dot q(t+a), t+a)\mathrm{dt}$ will be maximized. This is the same as saying if I observe this today, I will observe the same thing happen if I repeat this later on. By the same logic we can also say that $q(t+b)$ is a path that will extremize $L$ (thinking about if I perform an experiment b units of time before performing another), so we can rewrite the above as $L(q,q',t+a)$ will be maximized/is a valid Lagrangian for our system

and the action of $-q(t)$ will be maximized (in one dimension, the negative can be replaced by any rotation matrix)--if I throw a ball in the +x direction it will evolve the same way if thrown in the -x direction (isotropy). We ignore the origin of the motion since by homogeneity we can shift it anywhere and still have a valid path.

However, I now realize that this might to stated too abstractly. If I try to find a Lagrangian for free space where I am right now as opposed to 5 meters away I will never be able to differentiate the two. If I found a way to do so, space would not be homogenous. Therefore, I --SHOULD-- be able to make my statement stricter: not only will $L(q+a,q',t)$ be maximized over a time interval when $L(q,q',t)$ is maximized over that interval, but $L(q+a,q',t)=L(q,q',t)$ (keep in mind this is talking about free space, if we were in an area with a potential, if my friend was trying to evaluate a Lagrangian in another location he would be able to differentiate the system in his location as opposed to mine. If we had interacting particles the only thing we could say is that shifting both of them the same amount will maximize the action, but we definitely could find a way to write a different Lagrangian). We quickly get that $L_q=0$ so L does not depend on $q$. Similar argument applies for homogeneity of time and isotropy.

Is what I stated a valid interpretation or am I misled?